# Stack usage in C vs in Java

Tags: java, c, stack

I am learning about the usage of stack and I notice that they are used differently, or apparently so, in C and Java. For example, the code below written in C will not work because it will clobber "name"

```
char* getName(){
char name[32];
scanf( "%s",name);
return name;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
char *myName = getName();

printf("%s", myName);
}
```

However, if I write something similar in Java, it works just fine:

```
public static String getName(){
String name = "A name";
return name ; 

}

static void main(String[] args){
String name = getName();
System.out.print(name);
}
```

I want to know why. Why does the stack not clobber in Java but does so in C ?

Comment: 1. The languages fundamentally differ. 2. Java uses memory management through garbage collection, while C does not. 3. Your C code invokes undefined behavior; Java has defined behavior.

Comment: Your functions for Java and C are not equivalent.  The C variant is taking use input to fill in a local array.  The Java variant is simply assigning a value to a String.  `char *name = "A name";` would be a closer analog to your Java function, and it would work fine.

Comment: It's better to compare C++ (`std::string name`) vs. Java as they both have memory management facilities C completely lacks. This is largely a product of C being designed to be low-level while C++ and Java have significant and deep abstraction layers built on lower-level primitives.

Comment: The stack IS clobbered in Java. It's just that function-local variables that get returned are placed on the heap, where they will be preserved until there are no longer any references, then garbage collected. That's part of the language.

Comment: Java barely uses the stack. All objects are silently heap allocated. And the reason the C code won't work is not because of some "clobber" but because you are returning an invalid pointer to the caller.

Comment: The equivalent C code to the Java example would be something like `String* getName(void) { String* name; name = StringInit(); return name; }`. Where "String" and "StringInit" is some string library using malloc().

Comment: @Lundin that is NOT true... Java uses the stack constantly.... just not for object memory allocation... references, primitives and return values are stored on the stack.... see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-virtual-machine-jvm-stack-area/

Comment: @JoelFan Obviously, and that's what I meant with barely using the stack. High level computers cannot function without a stack.

Comment: @Lundin... ¯_(ツ)_/¯ ... I guess I assumed by "barely" you didn't mean on every method call, method return, method parameter access and scoped variable access.... my bad, I guess.

And there were/are plenty of IBM mainframe architectures that function perfectly well without stacks... the main drawback is the lack of recursive calls.. you store the return addresses and parameters in the code memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, `new String` creates an object on the *heap*, not the *stack*. As such, `new` in Java is akin to `malloc` in C.

The equivalent of

```
// Java
public static String getName() {
    String name = "A name";
    return name; 
}
```

would be

```
// C
static String *getName() {
    String *name = String_new("A name");
    return name; 
}
```

where the `String` "class" would be defined something like the following:

```
typedef struct {
   char *buf;
} String;

String *String_new(const char* src) {
   String *string = malloc(sizeof(String));
   string->buf = strdup(src);
   return string;
}

void String_free(String *this) {
   free(this->buf);
   free(this);
}
```

There is no equivalent to C's `char name[32];` (an array where the elements are on the stack) in Java.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the memory for local variables is not allocated on the stack... only the reference is put on the stack.  The object itself is put on the heap.

Comment: The local variable is allocated on the stack; it is what holds the reference to the string object.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable, which goes out of scope once the function returns. Dereferencing that pointer then is undefined behaviour in C.

In Java, `String` is a managed object and is subject to garbage collection. So it will be retained until no more references to it exists.

C, in contrast, does not have managed objects nor a garbage collector. You have to take care of the life time of "objects" on your own.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the string is allocated on the heap, not the stack, and new memory is allocated for each string. It is actually not possible to clobber a string in Java, because Java's strings are immutable.